# speed up most recent query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, mysql-5.6

I am trying to get the 3 successful (success =1) recent records and then see their average response time.

I have manipulated the results so that the average response is always 2ms.

I have 20,000 records in this table right now, but I plan on have 1-2 million. It takes 40 seconds just with 20,000 records, so I need to optimize this query.

Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc91eb/1/0

The fiddle contains my indices too, so I am open to adding more indices if needed.

```
SELECT proxy, 
       Avg(a.responsems) AS avgResponseMs,
       COUNT(*) as Count
FROM proxylog a
WHERE  
        a.success = 1 
         AND ( (SELECT Count(0) 
                FROM   proxylog b 
                WHERE  ( ( b.success = a.success ) 
                         AND ( b.proxy = a.proxy ) 
                         AND ( b.datetime >= a.datetime ) )) <= 3 ) 
GROUP  BY proxy 
ORDER BY avgResponseMs
```

Here is the result of EXPLAIN

```
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+----------------+-------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys  | key   | key_len | ref                 | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+----------------+-------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| 1  | PRIMARY            | a     | index | NULL           | proxy | 61      | NULL                | 19110 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+----------------+-------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| 2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | b     | ref   | proxy,datetime | proxy | 52      | wwwim_iroom.a.proxy | 24    | Using where; Using index                     |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+----------------+-------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Before you suggest windowed functions, I am using MariaDB 10.1.21 which is ~Mysql 5.6 AFAIK

Comment: `EXPLAIN` on that might help illuminate the issue.

Comment: It'd also help if you explained what the intent was behind that inner query, plus why you couldn't do this as a `JOIN` operation. If you query this table frequently, consider making it a view and materializing it.

Comment: You are doing a correlated subquery for every success.  What is the overall purpose you are trying to achieve, and why this requires a correlated subquery. So for each one record of a proxy, you are getting a count of every record with on or greater date that succeeded too.  So a table of a 1+ million, it will take quite some time to do.  Please clarify purpose.

Comment: The proxylog is a log of every proxy request the system does. When the proxy finishes a request it writes to this table with its success  (0 or 1).  I want to get a list of all the successful proxies and their average response time over the last 3 successful requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to mimic row_number and follow @Gordon Linoff answer

```
SELECT pl.proxy, Avg(pl.responsems) AS avgResponseMs, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM (
      SELECT 
        @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @g = proxy 
            THEN @row_number + 1
            ELSE 1
        END AS RN,
        @g:=proxy g,
        pl.*
      FROM proxyLog pl,
      (SELECT @g:=0,@row_number:=0) as t
      WHERE pl.success = 1 
      ORDER BY proxy,datetime DESC
) pl
WHERE RN <= 3 
GROUP BY proxy 
ORDER BY avgResponseMs
```

Answer (score 2):

An index on `(success, proxy, datetime, responsems)` should help. `success`, `proxy` and `datetime` are the columns shared between both queries. `datetime` should come after the other two, because it is used to filter a range whereas the other two filter on a point. `responsems` comes last as this is the column the calculation is done on. That way the needed values can be taken directly from the index.

And please edit the question and include the DDL and DML also in the question it self. The fiddle might be down some day and the question therefore useless for future readers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, this reduce the query from 40 seconds to about 37 seconds. I believe the heard of the slowness is the dependent subquery.

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper: Yes, that's not unlikely. But in MySQL 5.6, if the version in the fiddle reflects the version you're really using, it's gonna be hard to express it another way. If you have any chance, upgrade to a better DBMS or at least version 8+ of MySQL. Window functions might be a helper here.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment back to my question, I think I know what your problem is.

If you have a proxy that has 900 requests, your first is still counting 900 (at or greater).  Second is counting 899, Third, 898 and so on.  That is what is killing your performance.  Now add that to having millions of records will choke the crud out of your query.

What you may want to do is have a max date applied to the first one you are querying against where it makes reasonable sense.  If you have proxy requests such as times are (and all are success values)

```
8:00:00
8:00:18
8:00:57
9:02:12
9:15:27
```

Do really care about the success time between 8:00:57 and 9:02 and 9:15?  If a computer is getting pounded with activity in one hour vs light in another, is that really a fair assessment of success times?

What you MAY want is to have some (your discretion) cutoff time, such as within 3 minutes.  What if someone does not even resume work going through a proxy for some time.  Is that really it?  Again, your discresion

```
 AND ( a.datetime <= b.datetime and b.datetime < date_add( a.datetime, interval 5 minutes )) )) <= 3 )
```

And the <= 3 is not giving you what I THINK you expect.  Again, your innermost COUNT(*) is counting all records >= a.datetime, so it would not be until you were at the end of a given batch of proxy times that you would get these counts.

So are you looking for the HISTORICAL average times, or only the most recent 3 time cycles for a given proxy.  What you are requesting and querying may be two completely different things.

You may want to edit your original post to clarify.  I end here until I hear back to possible offer additional assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to try writing the query using window functions:

```
SELECT pl.proxy, Avg(pl.responsems) AS avgResponseMs, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM (SELECT pl.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pl.proxy ORDER BY datetime DESC) as seqnum
      FROM proxylog pl
      WHERE pl.success = 1 
     ) pl
WHERE seqnum <= 3 
GROUP BY proxy 
ORDER BY avgResponseMs;
```

For this, you want an index on `proxylog(success, proxy, datetime, responsems)`.

In older versions, I would replace your version of the subquery with:

```
SELECT pl.proxy, Avg(pl.responsems) AS avgResponseMs, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM (SELECT pl.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pl.proxy ORDER BY datetime DESC) as seqnum
      FROM proxylog pl
      WHERE 
     ) pl
WHERE pl.success = 1 AND
      pl.datetime >= ANY (SELECT pl2.datetime
                          FROM proxylog pl2
                          WHERE pl2.success = pl.success AND
                                pl2.proxy = pl.proxy
                          ORDER BY pl2.datetime DESC
                          LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
                         )
GROUP BY proxy 
ORDER BY avgResponseMs;
```

The index you want for this is the same as above.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have an older version of MySQL that doesn't have windowed functions. Ill update the tag

Comment: What 'older versions' support row_number ?!?!?!?